# Discovering and communicating with USB devices in C++

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, usb, boost-asio

Just to se the record straight, I'm a total newb when it comes to USB communication. While I've dealt with lower-level serial communications (SPI, UART, I2C) on the micro-controller end of things, I have never dealt with USB nor the OS side of serial communications. So please bear with me.

I have an RFID reader/writer that has its own protocol which I use to issue various commands. I'm looking into using the Boost:ASIO library to perform the read/write operations I need.

However, the library is a little over my head and I'm seeking some guidance. Furthermore, while I am working in a Windows environment, I'd like to make my hardware abstraction layer as portable as possible. Along the same lines, I've had bad experiences in the past with (other programmers) hardcoding COM ports and I'd rather my program discover my reader when I plug it in, based off of the reader ID perhaps.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Some direction in this area

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking into libusb (http://www.libusb.org/) it has cross platform support for USB interfaces, and isn't that complex if you understand how USB works.

Comment: I've given it a lookover and it does seem attractive. However, my main concern is licensing. My application is closed source (not by my choice, blame the proverbial pointy-haired bosses). So I've kinda got to be wary of using open source stuff.

Comment: It's licensed under GNU Lesser General Public License, so as long as you don't statically link to it, or modify its source, you just have to include a copy of its license in release.

Comment: I should note, pay close attention to the static linking part. Some platforms don't really let you do that, notably in mobile devices. That unfortunately has the side effect of taking LGPL solutions off the table. However where its allowed, LGPL is both common and attractive as it gives you a library for whom you can study the source , but it also gives your customers the comfort of knowing your using well understood and widely trusted libraries in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Device detection is quite platform-specific, so you should define a cross-platform API between the OS-specific portion and the data processing.

For device enumeration on Windows, there's the `SetupDi`* APIs.  Device arrival events can be gotten with `RegisterDeviceNotification`.  You can inspect the "Compatible ID" which contains VID and PID, as well as the Bus-Dependent Device Description which reports the USB string descriptors, in order to recognize your own device.

On Linux, there's `udev`, which is capable of matching on VID, PID, and string descriptors and gives enumeration and arrival events for matching devices.

Once you use these OS-specific means to find the serial port name, you have a variety of cross-platform serial port libraries to open a connection and exchange data with the device.